# React hooks setter doesn't trigger rerender after array splice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a parent component like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Test from "./Test";

function App() {
    const [configs, setConfigs] = React.useState([1, 2, 3])
    return (
        <div>
            {configs.map(((oneConfig, index) =>
                    <Test
                        config={oneConfig}
                        remove={() => {
                            configs.splice(index, 1);
                            setConfigs(configs);
                            console.log(222)
                        }}
                    />))
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

and the `Test` component is like this

```
export default function Test(props) {
    return(
        <div style={{border: "solid 1px", margin: "5px"}}>
            <p>This is config {props.config}</p>
            <a href="/" onClick={() => props.remove()}>delete config{props.config}</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I wish that when I click "delete config [i]" a tag, the corresponding `div` will be removed, but it isn't happening that way.

After setting a breakpoint in the parent component at the beginning of the function and console line, I found out that after executing `setConfigs` method, the parent component isn't re-rendering.

Any idea why this is so and how can I achieve my goal of removing an element from `configs`?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you use react developers tools, can you check that it's indeed removed from the `configs` in the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem's in the `remove` prop:

```js
configs.splice(index, 1);
```

`splice` mutates the `configs` state, and mutating state directly in React is a no-no.

Try rewriting your `remove` prop like so:

```
remove={() => setConfigs(prev => {
  let left = prev.slice(0, index);   // Everything before configs[index]
  let right = prev.slice(index + 1); // Everything after configs[index]
  return [...left, ...right];
})}
```

This will set the `configs` state equal to the previous state without the `oneConfig` whose delete button you clicked.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Removing inside a map is really an awful practice, but i cant find another way to do the job.

Comment: I wouldn't call it awful, just be careful of what you're doing. On a side note, consider setting a `key` prop in test since you produce an Array of them through `map`. Something like `<Test key={index} ... />` will do.